# Spray Client I want to return String from Json response

Tags: json, scala, spray-client

Sorry, but I am new to Scala. I have read about Futures and Akka, however I still have issue returning a  string for my method.

I have a method getAuthString which should return Authentication String(or Token).
I have used spray Jsonsupport and I can print the result

```
def getToken(url: String, username: String , password: String) = Future[String]{

import MyJsonProtocol._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[AuthTokenResult[Entry]] = (addCredentials(BasicHttpCredentials(username, password))
  ~> sendReceive
  ~> unmarshal[AuthTokenResult[Entry]]
  )
val myfutureResponse: Future[AuthTokenResult[Entry]] = pipeline(Get(url))

myfutureResponse onComplete {
      case Success(AuthTokenResult(Entry(Content(authString)):: _)) => println(authString)
      case Failure(error) => println("An error has occured: " + error.getMessage)
    }
```

this unmarshal the json and print the desired authString. However, printing is no good to me. I know onComplete returns unit. I want to return authString so that I can use it somewhere else with another request. I think I will have to use flatmap or map, but I am not sure how. I need my method to return authString or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to return a `String`, you want to return a `Future[String]` - once something is async the only way to make it not async is to block, and that's (usually) a waste, making the whole async-ness pointless.

I'm not sure why you're wrapping the whole thing in a `Future` either - the trivial bits of computation can happen on their own, there's little value in forcing them onto a separate thread. So you want something like:

```
def getToken(url: String, ...): Future[String] = {
  ...
  val myFutureResponse: Future[AuthTokenResult[Entry]] = ...
  myFutureResponse map {
    case AuthTokenResult(Entry(Content(authString))::_) => authString
  }
}
```

So you use `map` to transform a `Future` into another `Future` with a computation. This will "pass through" errors, but you can use something like `recover` or `recoverWith` if you want to handle them in a particular way.

Then when you want to use your `Future[String]` in a Spray route, you can use the `onSuccess` or `onComplete` directives:

```
val myRoute = (path("/somewhere") & parameter("authData") {
  authData =>
    onSuccess(getToken(authData)) {
      authToken =>
        complete("Authed as " + authToken)
    }
  }
```

This will use the `Future` in a proper async, reactive way, without blocking.

Comment: Thanks @Imm for your prompt response. You have given me enough pointers and I am happy with your reply, however, pardon me for my ignorance. If I go via the routing approach, that means that all my code that needs to make an API call **/url/path+?authToken** will have to be in a single code block. Why can't I use something like **Val mytoken = getToken(url, ...)**, so that everytime I need to make an API request, I can then append token to my url in as part of my request parameter. You said this will be blocking If I did that, the problem is I will end up without a reusable code

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were just using spray-client. You could use a Promise to hold the `authToken`: `val authToken = Promise[String](); authToken.completeWith(getToken())` and then you use `authToken.future` in other code. Or you could use an actor. Or maybe your code doesn't need to be async after all, in which case you can just do `val authToken = Await.result(getToken(), 30 seconds)`. In that case it might be better not to use spray at all though - it adds complexity that's needed for high-performance parallel code, but simple cases could use a simpler library.